# batch script output file with double byte characters

Tags: sql, batch-file, encoding, double-byte

I am new to scripting and i cant seem to find the answer to this. I wrote a simple batch script to run a sql query and save the output as a .txt file. However, the results contain double byte characters (for Japanese data) which are being converted to question marks in the output.

This is the line in the script - I am hoping there is an easy answer (ie. adding some formatting code to the end of this line)?

```
sqlcmd  -E -Smyservername -h-1 -iCust.sql -o Cust.txt
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The output file's encoding is determined by sqlcmd.exe.

Comment: im sorry but can you provide more information?  i am very new to this and dont know where or how to set the encoding.

Comment: Please read [sqlcmd Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) documentation and especially the section __Input/Output Options__  with details for input and output [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). With using additionally the switch `-f 1252` you should get `Cust.txt` with codepage Windows-1252 which is the standard for North American and Western European countries for non Unicode text files.